# React Js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a data grid in reactJS that i need to populate with data taken by merging data from three tables.
The first contains the indexes and the other two are the elements to be displayed.
below is the code to populate the grid lines

```
const datiRighe = vocibilancio.map(voci => {
    const lista = listaattivita.find(elemento => elemento.id_lista_attivita === 
    voci.id_gruppo_att)
    const listasub = listasubattivita.find(elementosub => 
    elementosub.id_lista_sub_group === voci.id_sub_group_att)
    console.log("lista:", lista);
    console.log("listasub:", listasub);
    console.log("voci: ", voci);
    return {
        id: voci.id_voce_bilancio,
        idGruppoAtt: lista.denominazione,
        idSubGroupAtt: listasub.denominazione_sub,
        descrizioneVoceBilancio: voci.descrizione_voce_bilancio,
        totaleVoceBilancio: voci.totale_voce_bilancio,
        createdAt: voci.createdAt,
        updatedAt: voci.updatedAt,
    };
}, []);
```

in the three console.log I get the data I expect but for some reason `lista.denominazione` and `listasub.denominazione_sub` are not accessible.

This is the `console.log` of `lista` for example:

```
{
    "id_lista_attivita": 1,
    "denominazione": "Uscite da attività di interesse generale",
    "tipo": 0,
    "createdAt": "2022-04-12",
    "updatedAt": "2022-04-12"
}
```

this is the error I receive:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'denominazione')

I don't understand where I'm wrong. I ask you for help, thank you!

Comment: *"in the three console.log I get the data I expect"* - That statement doesn't seem to agree with the error you're getting.  Are you sure that (1) this is exactly where the error is coming from and (2) it's never logging `undefined` to the console for `lista` **or** `listasub`?  Can you provide any demonstration (even a screen shot) of this?

Comment: Hi David i paste a screen in the question. thanks!

Comment: I believe its because your map function is using data that is fetched in your useEffect - so since useEffect fires when the page renders, your map function is running before the data is fetched, causing the data to initially be undefined.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I think you're right, but I really have no idea how to get around this. Can you help me figure out how to do it? A resource or an indication on where to find the answer I am looking for? Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

These values are `undefined`:

```
const lista = listaattivita.find(elemento =>
  elemento.id_lista_attivita === voci.id_gruppo_att);
const listasub = listasubattivita.find(elementosub => 
  elementosub.id_lista_sub_group === voci.id_sub_group_att);
```

This happens when [no matching values are found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).  So the question becomes, how do you want to *handle* the case when these are `undefined`?

For example, you can use nullish-checking when returning the result:

```
return {
    id: voci.id_voce_bilancio,
    idGruppoAtt: lista?.denominazione, // <--- here
    idSubGroupAtt: listasub?.denominazione_sub, // <--- and here
    descrizioneVoceBilancio: voci.descrizione_voce_bilancio,
    totaleVoceBilancio: voci.totale_voce_bilancio,
    createdAt: voci.createdAt,
    updatedAt: voci.updatedAt,
};
```

That would result in the properties `idGruppoAtt` and `idSubGroupAtt` being `null` in the returned result.  Which may require you to handle `null` values elsewhere in your code as well.

Or maybe you want to return some default values, or throw an error, or something else.  It's up to you.  The point is that `.find()` *might* return `undefined` if the value is not found, so you just need to handle that scenario.

Comment: Hi, David,
thanks for your analysis. I don't know how to handle this. I am very new to JS and Reactjs. Could you give me some advice? Or point me to a resource where to learn how to manage this type of situation? thank you !

Comment: @ClaudioM: This isn't specific to ReactJS, this is just JavaScript.  It's physically possible for `.find()` to return `undefined` if it didn't find what you're looking for in the given array.  So you can't assume that the result will always be valid.  Look at the screen shot in your question, observe how the `console.log` *sometimes* logged `undefined` for `lista` and `listasub`.  So all you need to do is include in your logic what you want to do when they are `undefined`.  The example proposed in this answer is to add null-checking and allow the returned object here to have `null` properties.

Comment: Hi David, .find () will always find a value in the property lista.denominazione because in another part of the app it is always assigned. It seems to me that it returns undefined or null because react does not update the state of the variable when it should (surely due to my mistake)

Comment: @ClaudioM: It's entirely possible that you may be mis-using something in React.  But the code shown in the question has nothing to do with React.  Either way, re-asserting your incorrect assumption that ".find() will always find a value" doesn't make that assumption any less incorrect.  The problem demonstrated in the code is that `.find()` didn't find anything.  Looking at the code in your screen shot confirms this, because the initial state value for `listasubattivita` is *an empty array*.  `.find()` will never return a matched value from an empty array because an empty array has no values.

Comment: David, thanks for your point.
this is another error i get in my console.

--- Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. ---

I will most likely be abusing something in react, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @ClaudioM: It's certainly possible that your code can have more than one problem.  For any given unrelated issue, you are encouraged to open a new Stack Overflow question and include within that question a [mcve] which describes and demonstrates the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. The problem for me was the order in which I execute the GETs from the Database in ReactJs.
First the individual lists and then all the rest of the data.

Like This:

```
const [vocibilancio, setVocebilancio] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    getListaAttivita() // FETCH list one
    getListaSubAttivita() //FETCH list two
    getVociBilancio() // FETCH rest of data
}, [])
```